# Индикатор загрузки

Tags: php, битрикс

В общем есть отчет на сайте с постраничной навигацией. И есть кнопочка выдать этот отчет в excel. C постраничной навигацией никаких проблем, но вообще-то в отчете могут быть десятки тысяч записей и формироваться для выгрузки он будет скажем пару минут. Клиент хочет при этом видеть сколько ему еще ждать формирования отчета.
Так вот на данный момент есть ссылка на скрипт, который выдает не web-документ, а формирует файл и отдает его на скачивание браузеру.

Каким образом страница с веб-отчетом будет узнавать о процессе формирования excel-отчета? Какие варианты индикаторов можете посоветовать?
Сайт на битриксе.

Answer (score 1):

А есть смысл усложнять себе жизнь?

Если там реально много записей, то нет смысла делать индикатор того на сколько прошла или идет загрузка, постоянно дергать процесс не есть гуд. (но если интересно посмотри как делаются индикаторы для загрузки файлов на сервер)

А так можно просто показывать gif рисунок, того что происходит формирование.

Битрикс-сакс. Не стал бы вообще заморачиваться на эту тему.

ps ну и наверное пора принимать ответы на свои вопросы. 3 страницы вопросов и 42% принятых, не хорошо, люди ведь старались.

**//upd**
Что значит увидеть какое-то решение?
Писать вряд ли кто будет за тебя.
Если ты реально хочешь заняться этим, то сделай допустим txt файл типа int.
Далее ты можешь получить общее кол-во строк записей из БД.
Дели их на 100, получишь 1% от всех записей.(допустим 15К записей, значит 1% это 150 записей)
Далее, ты наверное в цикле обрабатываешь эти данные, отлично, тогда:

- у тебя уже есть значение 1% от всего объема данных
- есть цикл
- есть файл для запись пройденного "пути" по данным

В цикле прошел 150 записей запиши в файл новое значение равное 2, и т.д. пока до 100% не дойдешь.

Со стороны сайта у тебя должен быть ajax запрос на сервер, на какой-то файл, который должен делать только 2 действия открыть файл на чтение и прочитать значение в нем потом просто отдать значение обратно. На сайте просто берешь и показываешь его.

Обновлять каждые 2-3 секунды допустим. Вот тебе решение, можно писать куда-то в БД.

Я думаю понятно написал. Код писать нет смысла.

Comment: Битрикс - большой сакс, но я с этим поделать ничего не могу, контора на нем сидит.
Не делать - не есть ответ, у меня тз, и что-то делать надо. Поговорю еще с заказчиком, но пока хотелось бы увидеть какое-нибудь решение.